# Mysql + F5 load balance error

Tags: mysql, load-balancing, f5

Hy everybody  i have mounted a mysql cluster with F5 making the load balance for me! 
I have setup everything acording to F5 irules and created all the enties into my hosts file etc... but when i try to connect via the ip used by the server created into the F5 i get the following error :

```
 [root@BIH001 ~]# mysql -uroot -padminlocal -h10.251.1.209
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 0
```

Thx all. - i am stuck

Answer (score 0):

Well this is three months old, but i would check your SNAT settings on the device. Also checking the route outbound from the server to the bigip would help.

Comment: thx for the reply - i am still looking for the answer !! i will look into SNAT settings